# How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?

Tags: bash

How would I validate that a program exists, in a way that will either return an error and exit, or continue with the script?

It seems like it should be easy, but it's been stumping me.

Comment: What is a "program"? Does it include functions and aliases? `which` returns true for these. `type` without arguments will additionally return true for reserved words and shell builtins. 

If "program" means "excutable in `$PATH`", then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461).

Comment: Also relevant is [How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398028/56041) and [When to rehash executables in $PATH with bash?](https://superuser.com/q/999439/173513)

Comment: @TomHale It depends on which implementation of `which` you are using; which is not provided by Bash, but it is by e.g. Debian's debianutils.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @jano Since the context is _bash_, `type` would be preferable over `which`, since we know that it is available. Howeever, both `type` and `which` do not detect, whether a program **exists**, but whether is is found in the PATH. To see whether a program of a certain name "exists" in a file system, you would have to use `find`.

Comment: What about specifically for the test-then-execute pattern, is there a simple way to just directly attempt executing and swallow "command not found" errors reactively, without swallowing other types of errors? I'd think that would save a bit of runtime overhead in the common case and help avoid discrepancy cases where a command actually can work but the test thinks it can't.

Comment: What do you mean by _existence_? In your working directory? In some directory on your PATH? Anywhere on your hard disk? On any network share? Further, are you seeing programs as "executable files", or do you also include shell functions to your idea of a program? Please be a bit more specific when asking.

Answer (score 4431, accepted):

### Answer

POSIX compatible:

```
command -v <the_command>
```

Example use:

```
if ! command -v <the_command> &> /dev/null
then
    echo "<the_command> could not be found"
    exit 1
fi
```

For Bash specific environments:

```
hash <the_command> # For regular commands. Or...
type <the_command> # To check built-ins and keywords
```

### Explanation

Avoid `which`. Not only is it an external process you're launching for doing very little (meaning builtins like `hash`, `type` or `command` are way cheaper), you can also rely on the builtins to actually do what you want, while the effects of external commands can easily vary from system to system.

Why care?

- Many operating systems have a `which` that **doesn't even set an exit status**, meaning the `if which foo` won't even work there and will **always** report that `foo` exists, even if it doesn't (note that some POSIX shells appear to do this for `hash` too).
- Many operating systems make `which` do custom and evil stuff like change the output or even hook into the package manager.

So, don't use `which`. Instead use one of these:

```
command -v foo >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

```
type foo >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

```
hash foo 2>/dev/null || { echo >&2 "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

(Minor side-note: some will suggest `2>&-` is the same `2>/dev/null` but shorter – *this is untrue*.  `2>&-` closes FD 2 which causes an **error** in the program when it tries to write to stderr, which is very different from successfully writing to it and discarding the output (and dangerous!))

If your hash bang is `/bin/sh` then you should care about what POSIX says. `type` and `hash`'s exit codes aren't terribly well defined by POSIX, and `hash` is seen to exit successfully when the command doesn't exist (haven't seen this with `type` yet).  `command`'s exit status is well defined by POSIX, so that one is probably the safest to use.

If your script uses `bash` though, POSIX rules don't really matter anymore and both `type` and `hash` become perfectly safe to use. `type` now has a `-P` to search just the `PATH` and `hash` has the side-effect that the command's location will be hashed (for faster lookup next time you use it), which is usually a good thing since you probably check for its existence in order to actually use it.

As a simple example, here's a function that runs `gdate` if it exists, otherwise `date`:

```
gnudate() {
    if hash gdate 2>/dev/null; then
        gdate "$@"
    else
        date "$@"
    fi
}
```

## Alternative with a complete feature set

You can use [scripts-common](https://gitlab.com/bertrand-benoit/scripts-common) to reach your need.

To check if something is installed, you can do:

```bash
checkBin <the_command> || errorMessage "This tool requires <the_command>. Install it please, and then run this tool again."
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain what the `&>/dev/null` and `>&2` parts are for? The line seems to work fine without them too. Thanks.

Comment: @Geert: The &>/dev/null part hides the message 'type' emits when 'foo' doesn't exist.  The >&2 on the echo makes sure to send the error message to standard error instead of standard output; because that's convention.  They both appear on your terminal, but standard error is definitely the preferred output for error messages and unexpected warnings.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with 'advanced' i/o redirection in bash: 1) `2>&-` *("close output file descriptor 2", which is stderr)* has the same result as `2> /dev/null`; 2) `>&2` is a shortcut for `1>&2`, which you may recognize as "redirect stdout to stderr".  See the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide i/o redirection page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more info.

Comment: > Many operating systems have a which that doesn't even set an exit status,

I'd be curious to see which OS's do this.  "Many" feels like an exaggeration.

Comment: It should be noted that `command -v` returns true for functions. As such if you decided to wrap a program in a function with the same name, then you can't use `command -v` to check if the program is installed.

Answer (score 855):

The following is a portable way to check whether a command exists in `$PATH` *and* is executable:

```
[ -x "$(command -v foo)" ]
```

Example:

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v git)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: git is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

The executable check is needed because bash returns a non-executable file if no executable file with that name is found in `$PATH`.

<s>Also note that if a non-executable file with the same name as the executable exists earlier in `$PATH`, dash returns the former, even though the latter would be executed. This is a bug and is in violation of the POSIX standard. [[Bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=874264)] [[Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/command.html)]</s>
**Edit**: This seems to be fixed as of dash 0.5.11 (Debian 11).

In addition, this will fail if the command you are looking for has been defined as an alias.

Comment: On some operating systems the empty string is treated as equivalent to `.` , so that `[ -x '' ]` may return true if the user has scan permission on the current directory; this leads to a false positive. (Fortunately this only affects a few older systems that are technically not POSIX compliant.) More resilient would be `thing_path=$( command -v thing ) && [ -x "$thing_path" ]`

Comment: Warning - this also fails for builtins: `[ -x "$(command -v echo)" ]; echo $?` prints 1!

Comment: @spawn right... with `test` also fails.

Answer (score 234):

I agree with lhunath to discourage use of `which`, and his solution is perfectly valid *for Bash users*. However, to be more portable, `command -v` shall be used instead:

```
$ command -v foo >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "I require foo but it's not installed.  Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }
```

Command `command` is POSIX compliant. See here for its specification: *[command - execute a simple command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html)*

Note: `type` is POSIX compliant, but `type -P` is not.

Comment: Same as above - `exit 1;` kills an xterm, if invoked from there.

Comment: This wouldn't work on a standard sh: you &> isn't a valid redirect instructions.

Comment: @jyavenard: The question is tagged _bash_, hence the more concise bash-specific redirect notation  `&>/dev/null`. However, I agree with you, what really matters is portability, I've edited my answer accordingly, now using standard sh redirect `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: to even improve more this answer I would do two things: 1: use "&>" to simplify it, like Josh's answer. 2: break the { } into an extra line, putting a tab before the echo, for readability

Comment: I just put this one liner into a bash function if anyone wants it... https://github.com/equant/my_bash_tools/blob/master/tarp.bash

Comment: Fails on builtins and reserved words: Try this with the word `then` for instance. 
 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461) if you require the executable to exist in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 112):

It depends on whether you want to know whether it exists in one of the directories in the `$PATH` variable or whether you know the absolute location of it. If you want to know if it is in the `$PATH` variable, use

```
if which programname >/dev/null; then
    echo exists
else
    echo does not exist
fi
```

otherwise use

```
if [ -x /path/to/programname ]; then
    echo exists
else
    echo does not exist
fi
```

The redirection to `/dev/null/` in the first example suppresses the output of the `which` program.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using "which" for the reasons outlined in my comment.

Answer (score 102):

I have a function defined in my .bashrc that makes this easier.

```
command_exists () {
    type "$1" &> /dev/null ;
}
```

Here's an example of how it's used (from my `.bash_profile`.)

```
if command_exists mvim ; then
    export VISUAL="mvim --nofork"
fi
```

Comment: What does the `&>` do?

Comment: The `&>` [redirects both stdout and stderr](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) together.

Comment: `&>` may not be available in your version of Bash. Marcello's code should work fine; it does the same thing.

Comment: Fails on builtins and reserved words: Try this with the word `then` for instance. 
 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461) if you require the executable to exist in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 49):

Expanding on @lhunath's and @GregV's answers, here's the code for the people who want to easily put that check inside an `if` statement:

```
exists()
{
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
if exists bash; then
  echo 'Bash exists!'
else
  echo 'Your system does not have Bash'
fi
```

Comment: Willingness to learn and improve must be rewarded. +1 This is clean and simple. The only thing I can add is that `command` succeeds even for aliases, which might be somewhat counterintuitive. Checking for existence in an interactive shell will give different results from when you move it to a script.

Comment: I just tested and using `shopt -u expand_aliases` ignores/hides aliases (like the `alias ls='ls -F'` mentioned in another answer) and `shopt -s expand_aliases` resolves them via `command -v`. So perhaps it should be set prior to the check and unset after, though it could affect the function return value if you don't capture and return the output of the command call explicitly.

Comment: Why does this not work on `if exists conda; then`, even though anaconda is installed and returns: `usage: conda [-h] [-V] command...` when one enters `conda` in the terminal? (Note I verified your answer works with `if exists bash; then` on an Ubuntu 20 OS.)

Comment: @a.t. `which conda`

Comment: @Palec it is not just aliases. `command -v` displays also built-ins, functions and even keywords and returns 0 for those!

Answer (score 33):

Try using:

```
test -x filename
```

or

```
[ -x filename ]
```

From the Bash manpage under [Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> ```
>  -x file
>           True if file exists and is executable.
> ```

Comment: That means you need to already know the full path to the application.

Comment: The OP didn't specify if he wanted to check for a specific instance or for any executable instance...I answered it the way I read it.

Answer (score 20):

To use `hash`, [as @lhunath suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212), in a Bash script:

```
hash foo &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo >&2 "foo not found."
fi
```

This script runs `hash` and then checks if the exit code of the most recent command, the value stored in `$?`, is equal to `1`. If `hash` doesn't find `foo`, the exit code will be `1`. If `foo` is present, the exit code will be `0`.

`&> /dev/null` redirects [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) from `hash` so that it doesn't appear onscreen and `echo >&2` writes the message to standard error.

Comment: Why not just `if hash foo &> /dev/null; then ...` ?

Comment: If `set -e` was set, the `if...` part was never run.

Answer (score 17):

Command `-v` works fine if the POSIX_BUILTINS option is set for the `<command>` to test for, but it can fail if not. (It has worked for me for years, but I recently ran into one where it didn't work.)

I find the following to be more failproof:

```
test -x "$(which <command>)"
```

Since it tests for three things: path, existence and execution permission.

Comment: Doesn't work. `test -x $(which ls)` returns 0, as does `test -x $(which sudo)`, even though `ls` is installed and runnable and `sudo` is not even installed within the docker container I'm running in.

Comment: @algal You need to use quotes I think, so `test -x "$(which <command>)"`

Comment: @algal Perhaps `ls` is aliased?  I dont think it would work if the command has parameter.

Comment: I can't vouch for this answer, but I'd also recommend quotes. `$ test -x $(which absent_cmd)` returns `test: too many arguments`, while `test -x "$(which absent_cmd)"` is properly parsed and results in exit code 1.

Comment: @acorello, the `test: too many arguments` suggests that `which absent_cmd` returns a multi-word error message. An executable file having the same name as the message could exist.  Using `which` this way is just a bad idea.

Answer (score 15):

If you check for program existence, you are probably going to run it later anyway. Why not try to run it in the first place?

```
if foo --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not found
fi
```

It's a more trustworthy check that the program runs than merely looking at PATH directories and file permissions.

Plus you can get some useful result from your program, such as its version.

Of course the drawbacks are that some programs can be heavy to start and some don't have a `--version` option to immediately (and successfully) exit.

Answer (score 15):

There are a ton of options here, but I was surprised no quick one-liners. This is what I used at the beginning of my scripts:

```
[[ "$(command -v mvn)" ]] || { echo "mvn is not installed" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }
[[ "$(command -v java)" ]] || { echo "java is not installed" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }
```

This is based on the selected answer here and another source.

Comment: The `[[` and the command substitution are useless here. Simply `command -v mvn || exit` will `exit` if `mvn` is not found; but then with that fixed this basically just repeats the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

It could be simpler, just:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                
set -x                                                                             

# if local program 'foo' returns 1 (doesn't exist) then...                                                                               
if ! type -P foo; then                                                             
    echo 'crap, no foo'                                                            
else                                                                               
    echo 'sweet, we have foo!'                                                    
fi
```

Change `foo` to `vi` to get the other condition to fire.

*NOTE: always handle the negative cases first, like* `if !`. *It's best to give the program every opportunity to fail; makes testing super easy* `;-)`

Comment: I intentionally made it as simple as possible. The only way for this to fail would likely be to mis-type the name of the program. Outside of that, it should work under any condition.

Comment: Why did you enable printing commands as executed? (`set -x`)

Comment: `set -x` is the bash debugger. it helps to illustrate what's going on when people just copy/paste->execute a solution from sites like this; that's all. Comment/delete the line if you're done debugging.

Answer (score 10):

**Check for multiple dependencies and inform status to end users**

```
for cmd in latex pandoc; do
  printf '%-10s' "$cmd"
  if hash "$cmd" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo missing
  fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
latex     OK
pandoc    missing
```

Adjust the `10` to the maximum command length. It is not automatic, because I don't see a non-verbose POSIX way to do it:
*[How can I align the columns of a space separated table in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602732/realign-columns-of-file-in-bash)*

**Check if some `apt` packages are installed with `dpkg -s` and install them otherwise**.

See: *[Check if an apt-get package is installed and then install it if it's not on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-an-apt-get-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not-on-linu/54239534#54239534)*

It was previously mentioned at: *[How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/2075386#2075386)*

Comment: Non-verbose way to do it: 1) get rid of the width specifier; 2) add a space after your command name's printf; 3) pipe your for loop to `column -t` (part of util-linux).

Answer (score 7):

I never did get the previous answers to work on the box I have access to. For one, `type` has been installed (doing what [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) does). So the builtin directive is needed. This command works for me:

```
if [ `builtin type -p vim` ]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
```

Comment: The brackets are not part of the `if` syntax, simply use `if builtin type -p vim; then ...`. And the backticks are really ancient and deprecated syntax, `$()` is supported even by `sh` on all modern systems.

Comment: @nyuszika7h But these tests may fail: For example `builtin type -p if` outputs nothing and returns 0 whether or not `if` exists.

Comment: @jarno What's your argument there? As you say, it *both* outputs nothing and returns 0, therefore it makes no difference if you use `if builtin type -p if` or `if [ \`builtin type -p if\` ]`, except the latter is unnecessarily verbose and uses deprecated syntax.

Comment: @nyuszika7h They are both useless in testing the existence of a program called `if`.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted the same question answered but to run within a Makefile.

```
install:
    @if [[ ! -x "$(shell command -v ghead)" ]]; then \
        echo 'ghead does not exist. Please install it.'; \
        exit -1; \
    fi
```

Comment: Relies on Bash being the shell due to the use of `[[`.

Comment: Using `$(shell ...)` within a recipe is almost always wrong. The accepted answer will work fine in a `Makefile`, too. `exit -1` is not well-defined and the conditional is useless anyway.

Answer (score 6):

**`hash foo 2>/dev/null`**: works with Z shell (Zsh), Bash, [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash:_Ubuntu,_Debian_and_POSIX_compliance_of_Linux_distributions) and [ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell).

`type -p foo`: it appears to work with Z shell, Bash and ash ([BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox)), but not Dash (it interprets `-p` as an argument).

`command -v foo`: works with Z shell, Bash, Dash, but not ash (BusyBox) (`-ash: command: not found`).

Also note that `builtin` is not available with ash and Dash.

Comment: Great list. From which versions? On my system `command -v foo` works on `busybox sh` (BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-19+b3) built-in shell (ash)). It fails correctly with 127 when foo is not found and prints the path if it finds it.

Comment: For example `type -p if` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

**`zsh` only**, but very useful for `zsh` scripting (e.g. when writing completion scripts):

The `zsh/parameter` module gives access to, among other things, the internal `commands` hash table. From `man zshmodules`:

```
THE ZSH/PARAMETER MODULE
       The zsh/parameter module gives access to some of the internal hash  ta‐
       bles used by the shell by defining some special parameters.


[...]

       commands
              This  array gives access to the command hash table. The keys are
              the names of external commands, the values are the pathnames  of
              the  files  that would be executed when the command would be in‐
              voked. Setting a key in this array defines a new entry  in  this
              table  in the same way as with the hash builtin. Unsetting a key
              as in `unset "commands[foo]"' removes the entry  for  the  given
              key from the command hash table.
```

Although it is a loadable module, it seems to be loaded by default, as long as `zsh` is not used with `--emulate`.

example:

```
martin@martin ~ % echo $commands[zsh]
/usr/bin/zsh
```

To quickly check whether a certain command is available, just check if the key exists in the hash:

```
if (( ${+commands[zsh]} ))
then
  echo "zsh is available"
fi
```

Note though that the hash will contain any files in `$PATH` folders, regardless of whether they are executable or not. To be absolutely sure, you have to spend a `stat` call on that:

```
if (( ${+commands[zsh]} )) && [[ -x $commands[zsh] ]]
then
  echo "zsh is available"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

The `which` command might be useful. [man which](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)

It returns 0 if the executable is found and returns 1 if it's not found or not executable:

```
NAME

       which - locate a command

SYNOPSIS

       which [-a] filename ...

DESCRIPTION

       which returns the pathnames of the files which would
       be executed in the current environment, had its
       arguments been given as commands in a strictly
       POSIX-conformant shell. It does this by searching
       the PATH for executable files matching the names
       of the arguments.

OPTIONS

       -a     print all matching pathnames of each argument

EXIT STATUS

       0      if all specified commands are 
              found and executable

       1      if one or more specified commands is nonexistent
              or not executable

       2      if an invalid option is specified
```

The nice thing about `which` is that it figures out if the executable is available in the environment that `which` is run in - it saves a few problems...

Comment: Use which if you looking for any executable named foo, but see my answer if you want to check a particular file /path/to/a/named/foo. Also note that which may not be available on some minimal systems, though it should be present on any full fledged installation...

Comment: Don't rely in the exit status of which.  Many operating systems have a which that doesn't even set an exit status other than 0.

Answer (score 5):

For those interested, none of the methodologies in previous answers work if you wish to detect an installed library. I imagine you are left either with physically checking the path (potentially for header files and such), or something like this (if you are on a Debian-based distribution):

```
dpkg --status libdb-dev | grep -q not-installed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    apt-get install libdb-dev
fi
```

As you can see from the above, a "0" answer from the query means the package is not installed. This is a function of "grep" - a "0" means a match was found, a "1" means no match was found.

Comment: However, the anti-pattern `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` should be refactored to `if cmd; then`

Comment: This only works for libs installed via `dpkg` or `apt`

Answer (score 3):

Use Bash builtins if you can:

```
which programname
```

...

```
type -P programname
```

Comment: Huh?  `which` is not a Bash builtin.

Comment: type -P programname is to be preferred, see accepted answer

Comment: @RobertG All I see is that `-P` isn't POSIX.  Why is `type -P` preferred?

Comment: I should have phrased that "to be preferred in bash environments" - as I intentded to answer the bash-specific previous comment. Anyhow, that was years ago - I guess I should just, again, point you to the answer marked as "accpeted"

Answer (score 3):

This will tell according to the location if the program exist or not:

```sh
    if [ -x /usr/bin/yum ]; then
        echo "This is Centos"
    fi
```

Comment: Yes i added this command if you need to install a package in the sevrer, Open suse, centos, Debian

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there isn't any portable and 100% reliable way due to dangling `alias`es. For example:

```
alias john='ls --color'
alias paul='george -F'
alias george='ls -h'
alias ringo=/
```

Of course, only the last one is problematic (no offence to Ringo!). But all of them are valid `alias`es from the point of view of `command -v`.

In order to reject dangling ones like `ringo`, we have to parse the output of the shell built-in `alias` command and recurse into them (`command -v` isn't a superior to `alias` here.) There isn't any portable solution for it, and even a Bash-specific solution is rather tedious.

Note that a solution like this will unconditionally reject `alias ls='ls -F'`:

```
test() { command -v $1 | grep -qv alias }
```

Comment: Good point. However, when run from inside a bash script, aliases are not visible.

Comment: There's also a problem, it will return false when the command 'alias' is checked. When it should return true. Example: test "alias"

Comment: I just tested and using `shopt -u expand_aliases` ignores/hides these aliases and `shopt -s expand_aliases` shows them via `command -v`.

Comment: Perhaps this could simply be construed as yet another reason to avoid aliases.

Answer (score 1):

If you guys/gals can't get the things in answers here to work and are pulling hair out of your back, try to run the same command using `bash -c`. Just look at this somnambular delirium. This is what really happening when you run $(sub-command):

First. It can give you completely different output.

```
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
$ bash -c "command -v ls"
/bin/ls
```

Second. It can give you no output at all.

```
$ command -v nvm
nvm
$ bash -c "command -v nvm"
$ bash -c "nvm --help"
bash: nvm: command not found
```

Comment: The differences are caused by the difference between interactive and non-interactive mode of the shell. Your ~/.bashrc is read only when the shell is non-login and interactive. The second one looks odd though, because this must be caused by a difference in PATH environment variable, but subshells inherit the environment.

Comment: In my case `.bashrc` have a `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` prepended by `# If not running interactively, don't do anything` so I guess that is a reason why even explicit sourcing of bashrc in non-interactive mode doesn't help. The problem can be workarounded by calling a script with a http://ss64.com/bash/source.html dot operator `. ./script.sh` but that is not a thing one would like to remember to type each time.

Comment: Sourcing scripts that are not supposed to be sourced is a bad idea. All I was trying to say is that your answer has little to do with the question being asked and much to do with Bash and its (non-)interactive mode.

Comment: If it explained what is going on in these cases, it would be a helpful addendum to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${apt-cache show program}
if [[ $a == 0 ]]
then
echo "the program doesn't exist"
else
echo "the program exists"
fi
```

#program is not literal, you can change it to the program's name you want to check

Comment: The curly braces are a syntax error. `apt-cache` is not a standard utility, and only exists on Debian-based distributions. [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I had to check if Git was installed as part of deploying our [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server. My final Bash script was as follows (Ubuntu server):

```
if ! builtin type -p git &>/dev/null; then
  sudo apt-get -y install git-core
fi
```

Comment: The conditional is rather useless, modulo the startup time to run apt-get, as apt-get will be satisfied and exit if git-core is already installed.

Comment: Its startup time is non-negligible, but the more important motivation is `sudo`: without the conditional, it would always stop and ask for password (unless you did a sudo recently).  BTW, it may be useful to do `sudo -p "Type your password to install missing git-core: "` so the prompt doesn't come out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic Bash's `type -P cmd`, we can use the POSIX compliant `env -i type cmd 1>/dev/null 2>&1`.

```
man env
# "The option '-i' causes env to completely ignore the environment it inherits."
# In other words, there are no aliases or functions to be looked up by the type command.

ls() { echo 'Hello, world!'; }

ls
type ls
env -i type ls

cmd=ls
cmd=lsx
env -i type $cmd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "$cmd not found"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? On which systems does this actually work for you? `type` seems to be a `builtin` in most shells so this can't work because `env` uses `execvp` to run `command` so `command` cannot be a `builtin` (and the `builtin` will always be run within the same environment). This fails for me in `bash`, `ksh93`, `zsh`, `busybox [a]sh` and `dash` all of which provide `type` as a shell builtin.

Answer (score 0):

The hash-variant has one pitfall: On the command line you can for example type in

```
one_folder/process
```

to have process executed. For this the parent folder of one_folder must be in *$PATH*. But when you try to hash this command, it will always succeed:

```
hash one_folder/process; echo $? # will always output '0'
```

Comment: "For this the parent folder of one_folder must be in `$PATH`"—This is completely inaccurate.  Try it.  For this to work, one_folder must be in the *current directory*.

Answer (score 0):

I second the use of "command -v". E.g. like this:

```
md=$(command -v mkdirhier) ; alias md=${md:=mkdir}  # bash

emacs="$(command -v emacs) -nw" || emacs=nano
alias e=$emacs
[[ -z $(command -v jed) ]] && alias jed=$emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any external `type` command available (as taken for granted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/6205510#6205510)), we can use POSIX compliant `env -i sh -c 'type cmd 1>/dev/null 2>&1'`:

```
# Portable version of Bash's type -P cmd (without output on stdout)
typep() {
   command -p env -i PATH="$PATH" sh -c '
      export LC_ALL=C LANG=C
      cmd="$1"
      cmd="`type "$cmd" 2>/dev/null || { echo "error: command $cmd not found; exiting ..." 1>&2; exit 1; }`"
      [ $? != 0 ] && exit 1
      case "$cmd" in
        *\ /*) exit 0;;
            *) printf "%s\n" "error: $cmd" 1>&2; exit 1;;
      esac
   ' _ "$1" || exit 1
}

# Get your standard $PATH value
#PATH="$(command -p getconf PATH)"
typep ls
typep builtin
typep ls-temp
```

At least on [Mac OS X v10.6.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) using Bash 4.2.24(2) `command -v ls` does not match a moved `/bin/ls-temp`.

Answer (score 0):

My setup for a [Debian](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20exitting) server:

I had the problem when multiple packages contained the same name.

For example `apache2`. So this was my solution:

```
function _apt_install() {
    apt-get install -y $1 > /dev/null
}

function _apt_install_norecommends() {
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $1 > /dev/null
}
function _apt_available() {
    if [ `apt-cache search $1 | grep -o "$1" | uniq | wc -l` = "1" ]; then
        echo "Package is available : $1"
        PACKAGE_INSTALL="1"
    else
        echo "Package $1 is NOT available for install"
        echo  "We can not continue without this package..."
        echo  "Exitting now.."
        exit 0
    fi
}
function _package_install {
    _apt_available $1
    if [ "${PACKAGE_INSTALL}" = "1" ]; then
        if [ "$(dpkg-query -l $1 | tail -n1 | cut -c1-2)" = "ii" ]; then
             echo  "package is already_installed: $1"
        else
            echo  "installing package : $1, please wait.."
            _apt_install $1
            sleep 0.5
        fi
    fi
}

function _package_install_no_recommends {
    _apt_available $1
    if [ "${PACKAGE_INSTALL}" = "1" ]; then
        if [ "$(dpkg-query -l $1 | tail -n1 | cut -c1-2)" = "ii" ]; then
             echo  "package is already_installed: $1"
        else
            echo  "installing package : $1, please wait.."
            _apt_install_norecommends $1
            sleep 0.5
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to check if a program exists **and is really a program, not a Bash built-in command**, then `command`, `type` and `hash` are not appropriate for testing as they all return 0 exit status for built-in commands.

For example, there is the **time** program which offers more features than the **time** built-in command. To check if the program exists, I would suggest using `which` as in the following example:

```
# First check if the time program exists
timeProg=`which time`
if [ "$timeProg" = "" ]
then
  echo "The time program does not exist on this system."
  exit 1
fi

# Invoke the time program
$timeProg --quiet -o result.txt -f "%S %U + p" du -sk ~
echo "Total CPU time: `dc -f result.txt` seconds"
rm result.txt
```

Comment: This is not poxis. Not work in modern distors debian based. If not exists return "time not found"

Comment: Can you give an example of `hash` telling wrong that there exists an executable by the name of the given argument?

Answer (score -1):

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Commands found in the hash table are checked for existence before being
# executed and non-existence forces a normal PATH search.
shopt -s checkhash

function exists() {
 local mycomm=$1; shift || return 1

 hash $mycomm 2>/dev/null || \
 printf "\xe2\x9c\x98 [ABRT]: $mycomm: command does not exist\n"; return 1;
}
readonly -f exists

exists notacmd
exists bash
hash
bash -c 'printf "Fin.\n"'
```

Result

```
✘ [ABRT]: notacmd: command does not exist
hits    command
   0    /usr/bin/bash
Fin.
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are already [following safe shell practices](https://sipb.mit.edu/doc/safe-shell/):

```
set -eu -o pipefail
shopt -s failglob

./dummy --version 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

This assumes the command can be invoked in such a way that it does (almost) nothing, like reporting its version or showing help.

If the `dummy` command is not found, Bash exits with the following error...

```
./my-script: line 8: dummy: command not found
```

This is more useful and less verbose than the other `command -v` (and similar) answers because the error message is auto generated and also contains a relevant line number.

Comment: This answer is very unclear to those who are not good with shell as it does not state how this code is supposed to be used and it differs from many other answers in that the failed branch of the test for `dummy`'s existence is out of hands of the script's author. Also, it lacks explanation of how it works and that it changes settings of the execution environment.

Comment: This is a Bash question, but it might be worth mentioning that the non-POSIX `shopt` call can be replaced with POSIX `set -f`, which is shorter and portable. The [pipefail option is not supported in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set), though, and there is no alternative, AFAIK.

Comment: @Palec I am not sure how this is difficult. It's actually simpler as it relies on the shell to let the user know that the command can not be found and exits with an error, as requested by the OP. Let me know what I missed :)

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but this is what I ended up doing.

I just check if the command I execute returns an error code. If it returns 0 it means program is installed. Moreover you can use this to check the output of a script. Take for instance this script.

**foo.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world"
exit 1 # throw some error code
```

Examples:

```
# outputs something bad... and exits
bash foo.sh $? -eq 0 || echo "something bad happened. not installed" ; exit 1

# does NOT outputs nothing nor exits because dotnet is installed on my machine
dotnet --version $? -eq 0 || echo "something bad happened. not installed" ; exit 1
```

Basically all this is doing is checking the exit code of a command run. **the most accepted answer on this question will return true even if the command exit code is not 0.**

Comment: I'm not 100% certain if your last statement is correct. The most accepted answer uses the command `command` with the flag `-v` to quickly validate if its argument is a built-in or executable command that is found in `PATH`. So the statement `if ! command -v STRING; then ...; fi` will validate if `STRING` is a valid _command_.

Comment: This is a different approach where it checks the exit code of the last command executed. The accepted answer is probably best for most of the cases. This is an alternative if you want to go deeper.

Comment: This seems confused at the very least. It cannot work for e.g. `false` which returns a nonzero error code by design.

Answer (score -2):

```
checkexists() {
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
        [ -n "$(which "$1")" ] || echo "$1": command not found
        shift
    done
}
```

Comment: Code is useful, but words do accomplish a lot when posting after many other answers, try it sometime :)

Answer (score -2):

```
GIT=/usr/bin/git                     # STORE THE RELATIVE PATH
# GIT=$(which git)                   # USE THIS COMMAND TO SEARCH FOR THE RELATIVE PATH

if [[ ! -e $GIT ]]; then             # CHECK IF THE FILE EXISTS
    echo "PROGRAM DOES NOT EXIST."
    exit 1                           # EXIT THE PROGRAM IF IT DOES NOT
fi

# DO SOMETHING ...

exit 0                               # EXIT THE PROGRAM IF IT DOES
```

Comment: 1) This is an absolute path. 2) You only check whether the program exists *in a particular location*, rather than being callable. I could have something in `/usr/local/bin` instead and your code would exit.

Answer (score -3):

I couldn't get one of the solutions to work, but after editing it a little I came up with this. Which works for me:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -q linux-headers-$(uname -r)

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
fi
```

Comment: This only works for Debian based systems like Ubuntu.

Comment: Even for those systems it can fail if the command is not installed via `dpkg` or `apt`.

Answer (score -4):

I use this, because it's very easy:

```sh
if [ $(LANG=C type example 2>/dev/null | wc -l) = 1 ]; then 
    echo exists; 
else 
    echo "not exists"; 
fi
```

or

```sh
if [ $(LANG=C type example 2>/dev/null | wc -l) = 1 ]; then
    echo exists
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

It uses shell builtins and programs' echo status to standard output and nothing to standard error. On the other hand, if a command is not found, it echos status only to standard error.

Comment: `type` is (almost) fine, but the pretzel logic to check its result is probably what caused the downvotes here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/bash-if-statement-too-many-arguments

Answer (score -4):

I would just try and call the program with for example `--version` or `--help` and [check if the command succeeded or failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed)

Used with [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script), the script will exit if the program is not found, and you will get a meaningful error message:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
git --version >> /dev/null
```

Comment: What if I want to do something else instead of exiting the script?
Not all commands would have a `--version` or `--help` option.